# Joining onto NULL if Record does not exist SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

I have a query that selects customers from a table `CustomerDetails`, and left joins onto another table (`CustomerActivity`) to get their last login time and finally left joins onto another table (`OpenOrderDetails`) to get their last open order (if applicable). I also have a big WHERE clause filtering this data

A customer can only have one record in the `OpenOrderDetails` table at anytime. My query looks like the following:

```
SELECT CD.*, H.LastCustomerLoginTime, OD.OrderFiledDate, OD.OrderCompletedDate
    FROM CustomerDetails CD
    LEFT JOIN CustomerActivity H ON H.CustomerID = CD.CustomerID 
    LEFT JOIN OpenOrderDetails OD ON CD.CustomerID = OD.CustomerID
WHERE CD.OrderStatus IN (1,2,3)
    AND (CustomerType = 1 or (CustomerType = 3 and CustomerActive IN (1,2)))
    AND (OD.OrderFiledDate IS NULL OR CD.TimeStamp >= OD.OrderFiledDate)
    AND (OD.OrderCompletedDate IS NULL OR CD.TimeStamp <= OD.OrderCompletedDate)
```

My issue is that this query only returns customer records that have a record in the `OpenOrderDetails` table. How do I return every customer, and `OrderFiledDate`/`OrderCompletedDate` if present, and NULL if a record for that customer does not exist in the `OpenOrderDetails` table?

Comment: From what table(s) are: fields `customerType` and `CustomerActive`?  This is a common order of operations issue.  You want the filters on tables being left joined to occur as part of the join.  If they occur in the where clause the LEFT join then behaves like an inner join.  Logically the tables are joined.  The where clause then eliminates values not matching the criteria; including NULLS generated by the left join.  The is null check  on OD is a less common but acceptable approach to keeping the values from the left join, which is why I asked about CustomerActive and CustomerType.

Comment: *There's potentially more to this question than a simple where clause limit.  I'd guess that one or both `customerType` or `CustomerActive` isn't in customerDetails. and it too would need to be moved into the join or have the is null check.

Comment: what is `DLECS.CustomerID` on the 2nd left join?  Shouldn't it be `OD.CustomerID`?  Alias/table DLECS doesn't exist in the query as defined.

Comment: @xQbert, it's a typo, it should be CD. based on your question comments I agree with your concern, but selected answer tells a different story. this question looks suspicious to me at all ;)

Comment: *shrug* moving on :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move some `OpenOrderDetails` conditions to `join` clause

```
 SELECT CD.*, H.LastCustomerLoginTime, OD.OrderFiledDate, OD.OrderCompletedDate
FROM CustomerDetails CD
LEFT JOIN CustomerActivity H ON H.CustomerID = CD.CustomerID 
LEFT JOIN OpenOrderDetails OD   ON CD.CustomerID = DLECS.CustomerID
                    AND (OD.OrderFiledDate IS NULL OR CD.TimeStamp >= OD.OrderFiledDate)
                    AND (OD.OrderCompletedDate IS NULL OR CD.TimeStamp <= OD.OrderCompletedDate)
WHERE CD.OrderStatus IN (1,2,3)
AND (CustomerType = 1 or (CustomerType = 3 and CustomerActive IN (1,2)))
```

Comment: While I agree this is easier to read/follow. I don't see how it will change the results. the is null check of OD fields and use of OR would keep the values from the left join. So why would this work and user1501171 not?

Comment: Gotta admit I'm shocked this worked and your original query didn't  @user1501171.  I don't see where DLECS comes from...

Answer (score 4):

When doing a LEFT JOIN, referencing ANY of the right side table columns in the WHERE clause will turn it into an INNER JOIN. To get around this, simply remove  any and all predicates that reference "right side" columns from the WHERE clause and move them to the LEFT JOIN condition.

Something along these lines...

```
SELECT
    CD.*, 
    H.LastCustomerLoginTime, 
    OD.OrderFiledDate, 
    OD.OrderCompletedDate
FROM
    CustomerDetails CD
    LEFT JOIN CustomerActivity H
        ON H.CustomerID = CD.CustomerID
    LEFT JOIN OpenOrderDetails OD
        ON CD.CustomerID = DLECS.CustomerID
        AND (   OD.OrderFiledDate IS NULL
            OR  CD.TimeStamp >= OD.OrderFiledDate
        )
        AND (   OD.OrderCompletedDate IS NULL
                OR  CD.TimeStamp <= OD.OrderCompletedDate
            )
WHERE
    CD.OrderStatus IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
    AND (
            CustomerType = 1
            OR  
            (   
                CustomerType = 3
                AND CustomerActive IN ( 1, 2 )
            )
        );
```

Comment: Clarification: When doing a LEFT JOIN, referencing ANY of the right side table columns in the WHERE clause _without allowing for NULLs_ will turn it into an INNER JOIN.

Comment: @HABO - technically... yes you are correct... but there's no need to confuse someone, who's trying to learn, with odd-ball syntax.